# Excel. Форматирование повторяющихся ячеек текста которые есть в другой таблице

Tags: excel, условия, таблицы, форматирование, excel-формулы

У меня есть **таблица А**, я хочу, чтобы те слова которые есть одновременно как в **таблице А**, так и в **таблице Б** подсвечивались зелёным цветом в таблице А. Как выполнить это через условное форматирование немного не понимаю.[image: Попытка выполнения условного форматирования]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно *Использовать формулу для определения форматируемых ячеек*

```
=НЕ(ЕОШИБКА(ПОИСКПОЗ($A2;$D$2:$D$4;0)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

`СЧЕТЕСЛИ` сама умеет определять нужный диапазон, ей можно скармливать весь столбец - функция будет обсчитывать только используемые ячейки. Формула УФ для столбца `A:A`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]